# Regex grouping matches with C++ 11 regex library

Tags: c++, regex, linux, c++11

I'm trying to use a regex for group matching. I want to extract two strings from one big string.

The input string looks something like this:

```
tХB:Username!Username@Username.tcc.domain.com Connected
tХB:Username!Username@Username.tcc.domain.com WEBMSG #Username :this is a message
tХB:Username!Username@Username.tcc.domain.com Status: visible
```

The `Username` can be anything. Same goes for the end part `this is a message`.

What I want to do is extract the ***Username*** that comes after the pound sign `#`. Not from any other place in the string, since that can vary aswell. I also want to get the ***message*** from the string that comes after the semicolon `:`.

I tried that with the following regex. But it never outputs any results.

```
regex rgx("WEBMSG #([a-zA-Z0-9]) :(.*?)");
smatch matches;

for(size_t i=0; i<matches.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "MATCH: " << matches[i] << endl;
}
```

I'm not getting any matches. What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Is it essential to solve this using regex because it seems to me stream extraction functions could achieve this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your regular expression is incorrect because neither capture group does what you want. The first is looking to match a single character from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9]` followed by `<space>:`, which works for single character usernames, but nothing else. The second capture group will always be empty because you're looking for zero or more characters, but also specifying the match should not be greedy, which means a zero character match is a valid result.

Fixing both of these your `regex` becomes

```
std::regex rgx("WEBMSG #([a-zA-Z0-9]+) :(.*)");
```

But simply instantiating a `regex` and a `match_results` object does not produce matches, you need to apply a `regex` algorithm. Since you only want to match part of the input string the appropriate algorithm to use in this case is [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

```
std::regex_search(s, matches, rgx);
```

Putting it all together

```
    std::string s{R"(
tХB:Username!Username@Username.tcc.domain.com Connected
tХB:Username!Username@Username.tcc.domain.com WEBMSG #Username :this is a message
tХB:Username!Username@Username.tcc.domain.com Status: visible
)"};

    std::regex rgx("WEBMSG #([a-zA-Z0-9]+) :(.*)");
    std::smatch matches;

    if(std::regex_search(s, matches, rgx)) {
        std::cout << "Match found\n";

        for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << i << ": '" << matches[i].str() << "'\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Match not found\n";
    }
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d59b92ec5b9e13d)

Comment: demo page doesnt load

Comment: demo page does load, nowadays (I add, in case anyone was being put off by its 2022 status)

Answer (score 3):

```
"WEBMSG #([a-zA-Z0-9]) :(.*?)"
```

This regex will match only strings, which contain username of 1 character length and any message after semicolon, but second group will be always empty, because tries to find the less non-greedy match of any characters from 0 to unlimited.

This should work:

```
"WEBMSG #([a-zA-Z0-9]+) :(.*)"
```